# Ansible Check if lxd container with name already exists

Tags: ansible, lxd

Is it possible to check in ansible if a container already exists?

I tried the following:

```
- name: LXD | Check for already existing container
  lxc_container:
    name: {{ container_name }}
    state: absent
  register: check_container_absent

- debug: msg="{{ check_container_absent }}"

- name: LXD | Create dev container
  command: # script to create container #
  when: check_container_absent.exists
```

But the output of `check_container_absent` did not change after I created the container.

Another solution would also be to check the location, where the containers are stored, if a folder with the container name exists.

Is there a better solution than to check for the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation

> Containers must have a unique name. If you attempt to create a
>   container with a name that already exists in the users namespace the
>   module will simply return as “unchanged”.

You should be able to check if the container with name `container_name` exists or doesn't exist respectively by checking if the task reports as changed.

```
- name: Do container things
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Delete container if exists 
    lxc_container:
      name: {{ container_name }}
      state: absent
    register: delete_container

  - name: Reports false if container did not already exist
    debug:
      var: delete_container.changed

  - name: Create container if not already exists 
    lxc_container:
      name: {{ container_name }}
    register: create_container

  - name: Reports false if container did already exist
    debug:
      var: create_container.changed
```

Both of the above tasks will actually create/delete the object if it does/does not already exist though.

If you are just looking to collect *data* on on whether the object exists and conditionally perform some action later depending, you will not want to use the `lxc_container` module as it is intended to create/delete, not gather information.

Instead you'll probably want to just use the command/shell module with `changed_when: false` and store the output.

```
- name: Check whether container exists
  shell: "lxc list | grep -v {{ container_name }}"
  changed_when: false
  ignore_errors: true
  register: lxc_list

- name: Do thing if container does not exist
  debug:
    msg: "It doesn't exist"
  when: lxc_list.rc != 0
```

Comment: I think the second option fits my requirements the best, since the creation of the container is wrapped in a custom bash script.